# Show third-party feed on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have this wordpress site & the feed for categoy is shown as http://site.com/category/category_name/feed. This shows all the posts from "category_name" category. What I want here is to show a custom feed hosted from one of my other site & not the default wordpress rss feed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
$xml = '//site.com/category/category_name/feed';
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->load($xml);
            $item = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');

            //$data = array();

            for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){
                $title = $item->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
                $link = $item->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
                echo '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank"><h2>' . $title . '</h2></a>';
            }
```

and past this php code from where you want to display the feeds..

for more info visit <strike>[access cross domain feeds with php](http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/05/30/display-cross-domain-feeds-with-php.html)</strike> hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to display a feed from another site in a WP site, either just the feed or the complete feed content as a post.

See [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) and [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) and [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/) and [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)